# Integral of 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a 1-form: $f_1(x, y, z) \, dx + f_2(x, y, z) \, dy + f_3(x, y, z) \, dz$ in 3D. What is the integral of this over a 1-manifold?

I know that I can write my 1-form like this: $[f_1 \, f_2 \, f_3] [dx \, dy \, dz]'$, but I don't know what to do after that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to integrate, you need to choose coordinates. In this case, you need to parameterize your 1 manifold (call it $S$) as the image of a path $\gamma\colon (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Then the integral will be
$$ \int_S\alpha = \int_a^b \gamma^*\alpha = \int_a^b \alpha(d\gamma_t(1))dt = \int_a^b \alpha(\gamma'(t))dt$$

Comment: I've never studied differential geometry. This looks alot like a standard vector calculus path integral, but the notation in the last integral seems odd. It wouldn't be $\int_a^b\alpha(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)dt$? Of course maybe that's how you compensate for the dot product in differential geometry... I know my notation here doesn't really work totally because $\alpha$ isn't a vector field.

Comment: @jdods Yes, $\alpha$ is a 1-form, which means it evaluates pointwise  on tangent vectors to give a real number. Of course, we can use the ambient Riemannian metric (the standard dot product) to identify $\alpha$ with a vector field $X_{\alpha}$ using the pointwise equation $\langle X_{\alpha},Y\rangle = \alpha(Y)$ for all $Y$.  Thus, viewing $\alpha$ simultaneously as a vector field  and a 1-form, $\alpha(\gamma'(t)) = \langle \alpha,\gamma'(t)\rangle$ which shows that the integral you write and the integral I write are the same.